# Why is this "this + sibling" call failing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having some trouble with what I thought should be a simple sibling selector in jQuery.

The problem generates no error message, of course, it simply fails to select properly.  Inside a document(ready) function() I have the following simple code to first hide all of the popups, then wait for a person to click an image which will show the sibling pop-up:

```
//hide all the charm pop ups
$(".charm_pop").hide();
$(".charm > img").click(function() {
    $("this + .charm_pop").show();
})
```

My HTML is being generated by a Django `for` loop, so there will be many iterations of this simple image/popup combo markup:

```
{% for ch in charms %}
    <div class="charm">
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/charms/{{ ch.image }}" alt="{{ ch.name }}" />
        <div class="charm_pop">
             <p id="charm_name">{{ ch.name }}</p>
         <p id="charm_desc">{{ ch.description }}</p>
         <p id="charm_price">${{ ch.price }}</p>
         <form method="post" action="." class="cart">{% csrf_token %}
               <p>**some inputs and what not</p>
         </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, I simply wait for an image to be clicked, and when it is I select it's sibling and reveal that corresponding pop-up. Yet when I click an image, nothing happens.  If I replace `$("this + .charm_pop").show();` with `$(".charm_pop").show();` it does indeed show all of the pop-ups, so the click function is working, the selector is just wonky.

Am I misunderstanding how `this` is working in this context?

Comment: `this` is an object, but you used it directly in a string, so instead, your selector is looking for a tag such as `<this></this>`

Comment: So this: `$(this + " + .charm_pop").show();` should work, no?

Comment: no, then it will be looking for `<[object Object]></[object Object]>`

Comment: So am I not allowed to use `this` in a selector at all?

Comment: correct, unless `this` is the entire selector. `$(this).doSomething()`, or `this` is the context `$("p",this)` which is identical to `$(this).find("p")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When writing jQuery selectors the string `"this"` simply means "an HTML element `<this>`", so `$("this + .charm_pop")` will certainly not work.

Concatenating the string representation of an object with something else is also not meaningful here, so `$(this + " .charm_pop")` will also not work.

You should be using appropriate traversal functions instead, starting from `$(this)`:

```
$(this).next(".charm_pop").show();
```

There is a number of different ways to go from the clicked image to its sibling `.charm_pop`, but `.next()` is fastest and also semantically identical to the adjacent-sibling selector `+` that you are trying to utilize.

Comment: .next() us exactly what I was looking for, it's been so long since I've touched javascript that I forgot I had to set the context.  Thanks everyone!  I'll accept this as soon as I'm allowed, as it indeed solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is basically using the + css selector

```
$("this + .charm_pop").show();
```

`element+.class` which says "Selects all the .class elements that are placed immediately after  *element*

In your case it is looking for an element named `this`. I doubt you have any elements with the tag name of `<this>`.

Your code needs to be

```
$(this).siblings(".charm_pop").show();
```

or

```
$(this).next(".charm_pop").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
$(this).find(".charm_pop").show();
```